# sudo apt-key adv fails intermittently

Tags: circleci, yarnpkg

I am following [the instructions](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install-ci#circle-tab) for installing Yarn on CircleCI, but CircleCI is showing these errors when trying to check the key server:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv D101F7899D41F3C3
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.j5q2IRFiKK --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//apt.postgresql.org.gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv D101F7899D41F3C3
gpg: requesting key 9D41F3C3 from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
gpgkeys: key D101F7899D41F3C3 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv D101F7899D41F3C3 returned exit code 2

Action failed: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv D101F7899D41F3C3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message means that GPG couldn't load the public GPG key used to verify the package signatures. Try doing this instead:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg
```

The issue is that the `pgp.mit.edu` keyserver sometimes has outages, which results in the error message you're seeing. Loading the GPG key via URL should be more reliable.